# Node.js is not creating a directory

Tags: node.js, file, directory

I have the code below in a file named file-create-directory.js when I call this file on the terminal by node file-create-directory.js is giving me an error
I see it has something to do with the fs.exists module but I can't figure it out

fs.js:140
  throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function    at maybeCallback (fs.js:140:9)
 at Object.fs.exists (fs.js:218:3)

```
const fs = require('fs');



if(!fs.exists("views")) {

fs.mkdir("views", (err)=>{

   if(err) return err;

    fs.writeFile("./views/new.html", 'this is a new directory and data', (err)=>{

        if(err) return err;

       console.log('Directory and file saved')

    })


});

}
```

Comment: `fs.exists` is deprecated so use this method instead: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path

Comment: I see fs.existsSync works , I don't need asynchronous, this helped me, but what if I needed to check this without blocking, is there a different function I can use?

Comment: You can use `fs.access()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "exists" function of built-in "fs" module, which should get a callback.
If you would like to perform it synchronously without a callback, you should use "existsSync".

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback)